# Problem with defective eigenvalues in a second order system

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to solve the following system.
\begin{aligned}
x'' &= -x + y\\ 
y'' &= x - y \\
\end{aligned}
I reduce this to a first order system,
\begin{aligned}
x' &= x_1 \\
y' &= y_1 \\
x_1' &= -x + y \\
y_1' &= x - y \\
\end{aligned}

The eigenvalues are $0$, $0$, $i\sqrt{2}$ and $-i\sqrt{2}$.

I call the coefficient matrix
$$
{\bf A} =
\begin{pmatrix}
0&0&1&0 \\ 0&0&0&1 \\ -1&1&0&0 \\ 1&-1&0&0
\end{pmatrix}
$$
Now when I solve for ${\bf A}{\bf V}_1 = {\bf 0}$ for the $0$ eigenvalue, I get an eigenvector ${\bf V}_1 = (1,1,0,0)^\top$. When I solve for ${\bf A}{\bf V}_2 = {\bf V}_1$, I get the following equations
\begin{aligned}
&v_{21} - v_{22} = -1 \\
&v_{21}-v_{22} = 1 \\
&(v_{23}=v_{24}=0)
\end{aligned}
which do not have any solution.

P.S. I know how to solve this system using for $0$ eigenvalue with $(a + bt){\bf V}_0$ with ${\bf V}_0$ being eigenvector for the $0$ eigenvalue. I want to know what is wrong with the first-order approach.

Comment: Why do you want to solve $A V_2 =V_1 $ ?

Comment: In order to complete the chain of generalized vectors for a complete solution

Comment: Ok :-).There is probably an error in your computation as $(0,0,1,1)$ seems to be a solution of $A v_2= v_1$.

Comment: (0,0,1,1) does satisfy but I think it is in the null space and searching for a particular solution yields the above equations

Comment: You have $A v_2 =(v_{23},v_{24},-v_{21}+v_{22},v_{21}-v_{22})$, so it seems that $(0,0,1,1)$ is not in the null space but a particular solution of the equation $A v_2=v_1$ Am I mistaken ?

Comment: You are correct, it was a moronic mistake :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got your equations wrong. Solving
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
0&0&1&0 \\ 0&0&0&1 \\ -1&1&0&0 \\ 1&-1&0&0
\end{pmatrix}
\pmatrix{v_{21}\\v_{22}\\v_{23}\\v_{24}}
=
\pmatrix{1\\1\\0\\0}
$$
is equivalent to the equations
$$
v_{23}=1\\
v_{24}=1\\
-v_{21}+v_{22}=0\\
v_{21}-v_{22}=0
$$
which has solutions $\pmatrix{c\\c\\1\\1}$, of which one can select for instance
$$
V_2=\pmatrix{0\\0\\1\\1}.
$$